# Wordpress - Submit comments in home page

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a client comment section in homepage of my website and a comment form as well. I need to show my customers comments there but it should not be for any post.
I'm using this code to show comments but as you know it needs a post ID to get comments.

```html
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_id' => 388
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) :
?>
    <div class="client-comment">
        <span><a href="#"><?php comment_author(); ?></a></span>
        <p><?php echo comment_text(); ?></p>
    </div><!-- .client-comment -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Have you looked up any WordPress plugins for comments?

Comment: No, I don't want to use any plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "static front page" instead of the default blog list front page, then you can add the front page's ID into your command.

You can find the ID of this kind of front pages if you go to its editor page at the backend and check your browser's address bar.

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm not using static front page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the post table must have a FK (foreign key) instance of user_id. Post can have many comments, and a specific comment appears only on one post.

So, design your database, in accordance with this relationship.

> ```
>   Your user table -> user_id, Name, comment_id (FK)
>   Your comments table -> user_id (FK), comment_id, post_id (FK)
>   Your posts table -> post_id, comment_id
> ```

As you can see, comment_id appears on three of the tables use this property to join three of the tables.

Comment: I don't know how to do that and I doubt that this is the right way.